# Photoshop 22.3: Change photo perspective

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, perspective

I've stitched together a few screenshots using google street view and now I want to change the perspective of the photo.

It's current view is from the street, I want to change the view as though your looking down from a higher level.

Current view as below

[image]

The view I want to change to using perspective warp is as below.

[image]

Is this possible using perspective warp on photshop, if so, how do I do that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to achieve such perspective is to either 1) be at that position, or 2) use photos which were taken from such position.  You cannot change the perspective of a scene because the information is simply not available.

Comment: Thanks, but even with photoshop perspective warp?

Comment: @user2240778 What is _perspective_? Photographically speaking, perspective is the location of the camera's aperture when the photo was taken. So no "perspective warp" or any other feature which stretches/squishes/rotates the scene can change what was visible to the camera **from the precise point it was located** when the image was taken. Think about how we use the term, "from my perspective...", interchangeably with "from my _standpoint_" or "from _where I'm standing_...". That is literally what perspective is, and can't be changed after the image was captured, unless that info is in the file

Comment: Basically, perspective warp can simulate *rotation* of the camera, but not *translation*.

Answer (score 3):

You can't because the other perspective you want contains information that is not in your picture (for instance, the roof tops) while it would not show things that are visible in your picture, like the inside of the shop on the left, or the windows of the restaurant on the right (I assume you are not trying to transform the Rue Vavin en Avenue de l'Opéra).

Now, in pictures of architecture taken from ground level(*), vertical lines  are converging towards the top, so you can use a perspective transform to stretch the top and shrink the bottom to obtain the opposite feel. This also makes things close to camera (so, at ground level) appear smaller, but you aren't going to fool anyone:

[image]

(*) Because the lens axis is pointing up unless you take special precaution to keep the lens axis horizontal (wide angle camera and bottom cropped, or tilt-shift lens)